# Disable touchCarousel on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I go about disabling [TouchCarousel](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/) on screen resize? It works scaling down but it does not disable scaling up.. I need to somehow disable the TouchCarousel within the else statement.

```
    $(window).resize( function() {

    var w = $(window).width();

    if (w < 600) {
        $('#services').touchCarousel();
    }else {

    }
})
.resize();
```

this is what i have at the moment, but not sure what to add to the else statement to disable the plugin on larger sreens.... any advice?